# Formal and informal letters format

Tags: formal-language, correspondence

will you help me in giving (telling)  the correct format of letter writing, please?

I wonder If you tell me the format of both formal and informal letters.

I teach my students English but I'm using the old format, and I'd like to learn new ways of letter writing.

I'm in desperate need of them.

Answer (score 1):

Now here's something for **formal letters**.
THEORY: HOW TO WRITE A FORMAL LETTER FOR THE FCE EXAM
STEP 1

IDENTIFY WHICH OPENING AND CLOSING GREETING TO USE:

IF THE NAME OF THE RECEIVER IS GIVEN

OPEN WITH:

Dear Sir, → IF YOU KNOW IT IS A MAN

Dear Madam, → IF YOU KNOW IT IS A WOMAN

Dear Sir or Madam, → IF YOU DON'T KNOW IF IT IS A MAN OR A WOMAN.

CLOSE WITH:

Yours faithfully, → FOR ALL CASES

NOTICE THE COMMA USED AND WHERE THE CAPITAL LETTERS ARE PLACED

IF THE NAME OF THE RECEIVER IS GIVEN

OPEN WITH:

Dear Mr. Jones, → IF IT IS A MAN

Dear Miss. Jones, → IF YOU ARE TOLD HER NAME IS MISS JONES

Dear Mrs. Jones, → IF YOU ARE TOLD HER NAME IS MRS JONES

Dear Ms. Jones, → IF YOU KNOW IT IS A WOMAN BUT DON'T KNOW IF SHE IS SINGLE OR MARRIED.

CLOSE WITH:

Yours sincerely, → FOR ALL CASES

NOTICE:

1) WHERE THE COMMA AND CAPITAL LETTERS ARE USED

2) THE RECEIVER'S FIRST NAME IS NOT USED, EVEN IF IT IS GIVEN TO YOU.

STEP 2

YOU WILL BE REQUIRED TO WRITE ABOUT 160 WORDS, THIS SHOULD BE DONE USING 4 PARAGRAPHS.

EACH PARAGRAPH SHOULD CONTAIN ABOUT 40 WORDS, AT ABOUT 10 WORDS PER LINE THIS MEANS 4 LINES PER PARAGRAPH

AVOID WRITING PARAGRAPHS THAT ARE MUCH BIGGER OR SMALLER THAN THESE SIZES.

STEP 3

USE THE FIRST PARAGRAPH TO EXPLAIN YOUR REASON FOR WRITING AND START WITH:

I am writing to you because…….

START THE SECOND PARAGRAPH WITH:

Firstly,…….

START THE THIRD PARAGRAPH WITH:

Secondly,….

USE THE LAST PARAGRAPH TO EXPRESS WHAT ACTION YOU WANT THE READER TO TAKE AND START IT WITH:

I hope you will be able to……….

I LIKE TO CLOSE WITH:

“Thanking you”, “Yours faithfully”, OR “Yours sincerely,”

STEP 4

THE EXAM QUESTION HAS RED MARKINGS TO HIGHLIGHT POINTS THAT MUST BE COVERED.

MAKE SURE THESE ARE NOT MISSED

THE BEST STRUCTURE TO USE IS THE FOLLOWING

THE FEELING IN A SHORT DIRECT WAY → a)

THEN FOLLOW WITH SUPPORTING FEELINGS → b)

FOR EXAMPLE:

'SHOW CONCERN'

a) I am very worried about you.

b) I don't think you are eating well and you will get ill if you are not careful.

FINISHED CONTENT:

Firstly, I am very worried about you. I don't think you are eating well and you will get ill if you are not careful.

'SHOW SUPPORT'

Secondly, I feel you were correct to act as you did. You behaved as any normal person would and you should not feel guilty about what happened.

NOTE: AVOID SAYING TOO MUCH FOR ANY GIVEN POINT. PRACTISE BEING CLEAR, DIRECT AND EFFICIENT IN YOUR WRITING, WITH CORRECT GRAMMAR AND SENTENCE STRUCTURE

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Internet,; hope it helps.
Hints:

Imagine that you write to a real friend of yours.
Friends usually have names ;-) so address him/her with a name: begin the letter with Dear Joey/ Tim /Rebecca, etc.
Begin your letter with some general statements. Refer to the letter you have received from your friend and thank him/her for it or apologise for the fact that you have not answered the last letter soon enough.
Use the proper register. The letter is supposed to be informal so you can use contractions, informal linking words like well, by the way, anyway, so, colloquial expressions, etc.
You can use more-conversation-like statements or questions in your letter: You know that I had this exam, right? You think he will be able to come to the party?
Use questions to ask about your friend - arrange the next meeting, send greetings to his/her friends and family, etc.
End your letter in informal way: Best wishes; Love; Regards. Instead of these phrases you may put two XXs. They indicate sending kisses ;-)

Useful expressions: 
Thank you for your letter. It was nice to hear from you.
Your last letter was a real surprise. It was so nice of you to remember about...
Thanks a lot for the information you've sent me in your last letter.
I've just received your letter. I'm so happy to hear that...
I'm sorry I haven't answered earlier but I was really busy with my school.
I'm sorry I haven't written for so long but...

Looking forward to hearing from you soon.
Well, that's all for now. Will talk to you soon.
Give my regards to your Mummy.
I hope we will be able to arrange a get-together.
Do write back as I'm waiting for the news from you.

Sample answer:

Q: You are abroad spending your holidays in a very exciting places you have always wanted to visit. The people you travel with are really nice so you enjoy their companionship. Write a letter to your friend describing what you have been doing so far and what you still plan to do.

Dear Amy,

Thank you a lot for your last letter. It was a nice surprise to hear from you. I'm sorry I haven't written to you earlier but I had to organise some things concerning my trip.

As you probably remember I've always wanted to visit some unusual places. And now, at last, off I went! But you'd never guess where I've chosen to spend my holiday. It's Antarctica! You would never think of it, would you? I'm so excited about the whole event!

The people I travel with are incredible. It's their fourteenth expedition there. They know every path in the snow by heart and they are very helpful. They share their knowledge and experience with me. Would you believe that here everything is different? You even need to set your tent in a special way. It's all very challenging. Tomorrow we plan to move further North so I may not be able to stay in touch for a while.

Anyway, I'd like to meet you when I get back. Hope you are enjoying your holiday. Do write back soon.

Love,
Becky

[184 words]

---